# Node.js and nginx as a reverse proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx

I need to start with that I am new the nginx and was following tutorials to get to this point.

I am using Node.js and nginx as a reverse proxy. I am using multiple hosts in nginx to enable `prod.example.com` and `beta.example.com`.

When I try to setup a reverse proxy in order to get rid of the original URL ( 10.0.0.212:3333) and show my prod.example.com my application hangs with an error: "Can't find prod.example.com/admin". However with 10.0.0.212:3333 everything works fine.

This is what I used to setup the reverse proxy. What am I doing wrong?

```
location / {
    proxy_pass         http://10.0.0.212:3333;

    proxy_set_header Host $http;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X_FORWARDED_PROTO http;
    proxy_set_header X-Url-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

Comment: Do you use DNS name or direct ip-address of the nginx server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Showing the full config(s) would help; we don't know how your server is configured based on what you posted.

I'm guessing, though, that either a) your DNS is not pointing correctly at your nginx server, or b) your nginx server doesn't have the correct host name set.

FWIW, I also use the `upstream` directive rather than pointing directly with proxy_pass as the URL.  Seems to work pretty consistently. Here's an example: https://gist.github.com/cosbynator/3072833

Comment: Hi, the DNS entry works correctly as the login screen works. After the social login via passport the error occurs. But as said, only if i come in via demo.tymlez.com not via 10.0.0.212:333

Comment: My core point remains the same: you've not given us enough information to help you.

Comment: here is my config  :
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f42083ab7edbb1ca497a689feb61aa27

Comment: You said  you can get there via 10.0.0.212:3333, but can you also get there on the other three ports you have configured?  Also, you mention that it fails after doing social login; have you looked to see if there are errors in that process tied to server address?

Comment: yes - i did . there is no error message on the server at all. Is there a way to log the 'new' URL as I am seeing demo.tymlez.com/admin after login - which is the expected behaviour - meaning behind demo.tymlez.com is or should be 10.0.0.212:3333/admin

Comment: Sure, whatever your process manager (I prefer pm2) should have a logging feature that records each request.  As does nginx as you have it configured (the access_log directive).  You can tweak its configuration to provide different / more data: https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/logging-and-monitoring/.  You can also use a logging middleware in your Node app which you can use to log as verbosely as you want.